# Get fragment from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Hardly can't get fragment from backstack, even start thinking of keeping in in singleton which is probably bad.
Saved to backstack like this and all time try to get it by tag or something gives me error.

```
Fragment fragment = UserProfileFragment.newInstance(null);
                        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES, fragment);
                        trans.addToBackStack("profile");
                        trans.commit();
```

It just return me null here so I can't use this fragment. No logs.

```
Fragment fragment2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("profile");
```

Comment: Please post the error you get (complete stack trace and/or logcat dump)

Comment: Added code, maybe I am adding tag not correctly?

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for help.

Comment: Are you checking for the fragment immediately after adding it to the back trace? (if not, try that to see immediately if it's added) Are you getting an exception somewhere that you cannot commit the transaction after saveInstanceState was called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag")`

is only used when you have added a fragment with specific tag for e.g.

`fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.order_container,mProfileFragment,"profile");`

or

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.order_container,mProfileFragment,"sometag");`

Then you will be able to find this fragment by the tag.

**In your case** you are adding a transaction to backstack so you will not be able to find that fragment by tag. You just adding a transaction to backstack thats it not a fragment. And also your fragment was removed from the activity and destroyed so you have to revert the transaction by popping backstack instead of finding that fragment by tag.
You have to call

`getFragmentManager().popBackStack("profile");`

to get that fragment back to the activity and make it visible on screen.