# How to find the fragment in back stack and just show it in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Activity` where I load **3** `fragments` one after another

- `FragmentA`
- `FragmentB`
- `FragmentC`

Flow is Like this **I have used Adding fragment one above another**

***Start***-`Activity` -----> *Load* `FragmentA` ----> *Load* `FragmentB` ----> Load `FragmentC`

---

## *What I am trying to do now is:*

Now assuming now `FragmentC` is the top fragment shown

I want to find the `FragmentA` from the stack and just show it instead of creating a `fragmentA` all over again

---

*Code I have used to add fragmentA is for Example:*

```
            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = null;
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentA.class.getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, FragmentA.class.getSimpleName());

            if(fragment!=null && fragmentTransaction!=null){
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
```

Comment: instead of creating new fragment, find the fragment by tag or id. for more have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139709/5110595)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getBackStackEntryAt(int)) method, from there you can go back to any fragment of your history…

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the back stack entries, meanwhile, if you find any matching Fragment by id or tag, just pop back stack inclusive with fragment A's name/tag so that the fragment A is just displayed rather than adding once again.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a tag, `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentA.class.getSimpleName());` to the transaction , you can use the same tag to find the fragment in the backstack, before creating a new frgament, check the backstack for the fragment using `findFragmentByTag` on the fragment manager, if it exist, the method returns the fragment otherwise null

Answer (score 0):

The example code to retrieve a fragment by Tag would look like this

```
FragmentA frA = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentA.class.getSimpleName());
```

and if it's not null you can reuse it in your container

```
if(frA != null) {
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
   //you could add this transactionn to backstack again here if you want to be able to pop it later
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, frA, FragmentA.class.getSimpleName());
} else {
   //if your fragment is null as it was destroyed previously you can create a new one here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **try it!**

```
val fm: FragmentManager? = fragmentManager
for (entry in 0 until fm.getBackStackEntryCount()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId())
}
```