# How i lateinit propert initialized viewModel outside onViewCreated in fragment

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I try clicked button in navigationview and filter movies in movies fragment

I need to adjust filterButton in mainactivity and get the data in MoviesFragment().filtMovie

MainActivity;

```
val navRight : NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_right)
        (navRight.menu.findItem(R.id.filtBut).actionView as Button).run {
            this.setOnClickListener {
                MoviesFragment().filterMovie(filtQuality,filtGenre,filtRate,filtYear,filtLang)
            }
        }
```

and MoviesFragment;

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        activity?.setTitle(R.string.movies)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.refreshData(sortMethod)

        movieList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        movieList.adapter = movieAdapter

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            movieList.visibility = View.GONE
            movieError.visibility = View.GONE
            movieLoading.visibility = View.GONE
            viewModel.refreshData(sortMethod)
            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
        }
}

fun filterMovie(quality : String, genre : String, rate : String, year : String, lang : String){

        viewModel.filterMovie(quality, genre, rate, year, lang)

    }
```

and my logcat;

```
2020-06-10 23:29:46.474 18721-18721/com.enesseval.moviedeneme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enesseval.moviedeneme, PID: 18721
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
        at com.enesseval.moviedeneme.view.MoviesFragment.filterMovie(MoviesFragment.kt:110)
        at com.enesseval.moviedeneme.view.MainActivity$onCreate$$inlined$run$lambda$6.onClick(MainActivity.kt:87)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-06-10 23:29:46.488 18721-18721/com.enesseval.moviedeneme I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18721 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
this.setOnClickListener {
           MoviesFragment().filterMovie(filtQuality,filtGenre,filtRate,filtYear,filtLang)
}
```

you create new `MoviesFragment` instance. But `onViewCreated` not calling, because this new fragment instance not added to the backstack and not showed. And this is why view model not initialized and you get exception.

You should find existing fragment in fragment backstack and call `filterMovie` on it.

[get the latest fragment in backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702216/get-the-latest-fragment-in-backstack)

[Get fragment from backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139036/get-fragment-from-backstack)